# how can I append an entry to a fstab next to a last line entry?

Tags: shell

Hi Im writing a shell script that will append below entry to fstab on multiple server.

```
/dev/vg00/lv_berf       /opt/berf               ext3    defaults        1 2
/dev/vg00/lv_vberf      /var/opt/berf           ext3    defaults        1 2
```

But some fstab has different entry example

fstab on server1:

```
LABEL=/boot             /boot                   ext3    defaults        1 2
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
/dev/vg00/lv_swap       swap                    swap    defaults        0 0

########### ABCD specific FS  ############################################
/dev/vgabdc/lv_apal3                   /opt/apal3              ext3    defaults        1 2
```

fstab on server 2
/

```
dev/vgabc/lv_vabc       /var/opt/das           ext3    defaults        1 2
/dev/vgabc/lv_vabcoracle /var/opt/oracle/abc    ext3    defaults        1 2
/dev/vgabc/lv_vgdb20u01  /var/opt/vgdb20        ext3    defaults        1 2
/dev/vgabc/lv_dasredprairie     /opt/redprairie ext3    defaults        1 2
/dev/vgabc/lv_common     /opt/common            ext3    defaults        1 2
########### ABCD Failover filesystems  ############################################
/dev/vgabcd/lv_apal3                   /abcd/opt/apal3              ext3    defaults        1 2
```

I want it to be appended before "########### ABCD ..." and next to the last entry

fstab on server 1

```
LABEL=/boot             /boot                   ext3    defaults        1 2
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
/dev/vg00/lv_swap       swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
/dev/vg00/lv_berf       /opt/berf               ext3    defaults        1 2
/dev/vg00/lv_vberf      /var/opt/berf           ext3    defaults        1 2

########### ABCD specific FS  ############################################
/dev/vgabdc/lv_apal3                   /opt/apal3              ext3    defaults        1 2
```

fstab on server 2

```
/dev/vgabc/lv_vabc       /var/opt/das           ext3    defaults        1 2
/dev/vgabc/lv_vabcoracle /var/opt/oracle/abc    ext3    defaults        1 2
/dev/vgabc/lv_vgdb20u01  /var/opt/vgdb20        ext3    defaults        1 2
/dev/vgabc/lv_dasredprairie     /opt/redprairie ext3    defaults        1 2
/dev/vgabc/lv_common     /opt/common            ext3    defaults        1 2
/dev/vg00/lv_berf       /opt/berf               ext3    defaults        1 2
/dev/vg00/lv_vberf      /var/opt/berf           ext3    defaults        1 2
########### ABCD Failover filesystems  ############################################
/dev/vgabcd/lv_apal3                   /abcd/opt/apal3              ext3    defaults        1 2
```

I have a working script using sed

```
line_count=`ssh $i grep -n "ABCD" fstab | cut -d: -f1`
  next_line=$((line_count + 1))
  ssh $i sed -i  "${line_count}i\ '/dev/vg00/lv_berf       /opt/berf               ext3    defaults        1 2'" fstab
  ssh $i sed -i  "${next_line}i\ '/dev/vg00/lv_vberf      /var/opt/berf           ext3    defaults        1 2'" fstab
```

Problem is when the fstab entry has a space before ABCD it will append next to the space. like the example on fstab on server1 it has space before ###ABCD so when the script run it will look below:

```
tab1
LABEL=/boot             /boot                   ext3    defaults        1 2
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
/dev/vg00/lv_swap       swap                    swap    defaults        0 0

/dev/vg00/lv_berf       /opt/berf               ext3    defaults        1 2
/dev/vg00/lv_vberf      /var/opt/berf           ext3    defaults        1 2
########### ABCD specific FS  ############################################
/dev/vgabdc/lv_apal3                   /opt/apal3              ext3    defaults        1 2
```

How can a fix that with out affecting the other entry on fstab on server 2 which has different last entry?

Comment: Use the `flag` tag at the bottom of your question and ask a moderator to move it to http://unix.stackexchange.com ... Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

use function addmntent()

see man page of addmntent

Comment: can I use this in a shell script? do you have sample where this is used in a shell or bash scripting

Comment: follow this link http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/51226-calling-c-function-froma-shell-script.html